# Kotlin I can't add element to the end of the arrayOf

Tags: android, kotlin

the problem is, that I can't understand differences between:
`ARRAY OF`, `LIST OF` and `ARRAY LIST OF`

I know, that arrays are mutable in nature, but list not. When I try to add something at the end of the simple array, there is no function like `ADD` and I have to improvise, but is in `mutableListOf` but in `ListOf` there is no! Why? Lists can change their sizes, and I don't understand why `ListOf` doesn't have function like `.add`? Can someone explain me in simple words?

Comment: listOf<T>() simply returns List<T>. Methods in this interface support only read-only access to the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When coming to a language that has functional constructs like Kotlin, one thing to pay attention to is [**mutability**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#:%7E:text=In%20object%2Doriented%20and%20functional,modified%20after%20it%20is%20created.)

> An immutable object (unchangeable object) is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created.

Immutable objects are useful because they are inherently thread-safe. Other benefits are that they are simpler to understand and reason about and offer higher security than mutable objects.

To answer your question:

- [`arrayOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of.html) return an `Array`. Kotlin's array elements can be changed so yes you are right, it is ***mutable***. But on the other hand, its size is fixed. That's the reason you cannot invoke `add` on an array.
- [`listOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) return an ***read-only list***, so you cannot suppose to add more elements into it or change its element.
- [`arrayListOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html) return an `ArrayList` which is an implementation of ***mutable list***. You can add more elements to this list, remove elements as well as change its element.

---

**UPDATE 2/12/2020**

Thank you for pointing it out, Alex.T. I need to correct one thing. `listOf()` doesn't return an immutable list, actually it returns a ***read-only*** list.

A read-only list is almost the same as an immutable list. It prevents being modified; however, if the underlying list is modified, the read-only list is changed too. You can modify the underlying list by casting it to mutable, or change it from Java.